# Will the bouncing particle exert greater force on the surface?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, collision, classical-mechanics

Imagine elastic collision and no energy is lost from the system.

A particle is emitted from the bottom of a box. The box is in inertial motion. The particle hits the top of the box and travels in opposite direction with the same velocity. The particle then hits the bottom and keep on bouncing. Will the force acting on the top and bottom of the box increase when the rate of bouncing of the particle increases?

What if the system is on the surface of the earth? What will be the difference between the force acting on the top and that on bottom of the box? Is it equal to the weight of the particle? So will the difference in the force acting on the top and that on the bottom of the box be amplified when the particle undergoes repeated bouncing?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: not homework. It is my own question. I wonder whether the particle bouncing in a closed container will exert a greater force on the wall if the length between two walls changes. And what does the effect of gravity on it?

Comment: If the walls of the bounding container move, then (assuming coefficients of restitution = 1) the particle will gain or lose energy in each collision with the wall depending on whether the contain decreases or increases in size, respectively.  This is similar to [Fermi's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_acceleration) idea of merging [magnetic mirrors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_mirror).

Comment: The box is at rest on the surface and the walls of the container are assumed to be stationary.

Answer (score 0):

> What will be the difference between the force acting on the top and
>   that on bottom of the box? Is it equal to the weight of the ball? So
>   will the difference in the force acting on the top and that on the
>   bottom of the box be amplified

The rebound of the ball can never be amplified. Even in an idealized example in which the collision is perfectly elastic and the coefficient of restitution is 1 (which no massive real object has) some energy will be lost to the walls of the box and each rebound will have less intensity.

Gravity does not help since *what you gain on the roundabouts you lose on the swings*

Comment: What does 'rebound of ball cannot be amplified' mean? Does that mean that the force exerted on the surface due to momentum change cannot be amplified, even for repeated bouncing ball? Sorry, i typed wrongly for the last two sentences. I mean 'particle' instead of 'ball'. I have edited it.